# Mac no longer connects to samba drive after samba is reinstalled

Tags: unix, smb

I have a ubuntu server running locally with samba. It was corrupted during the Ubuntu upgrade and I just reinstall ubuntu on it and call it a day.

On my Mac Mini, it appears it no longer connects to the samba drives even with the correct username and password. I am able to connect to samba on my other Windows and even Mac devices.

The window below just shakes to indicate the login is not correct even though I'm 100% sure that is the correct credentials. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Version of macOS on the mini having difficulty?  Have you tried removing the entry from your keychain and adding it back?